# Bootstrap 3 Vertical Alignment Across Multiple Rows and Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap.  I just started a project and came across a challenge regarding vertical alignment with Bootstrap's grid system.  Hopefully this community of experts will be able to shed some light and assist with a solution.

To better illustrate the issue, I have taken 4 screenshots (links attached at the bottom) for each of the lg, md, sm, and xs scenarios.  I hope the images make sense to you.

The problem is, while the lg scenario looks great and everything is aligned properly, as the viewport changes, the content of the 2 columns start to show misalignment.

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-centered">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h2>HEADER NUMBER 1</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <div>
                            <p>Teaser number 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit, interdum consectetur elit. Donec interdum dapibus lectus rhoncus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                        <h4>Sub-heading short</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                        <h4>Sub-heading longer</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div>
                            <p>Link to detailed page 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h2>HEADER DIFFERENT LENGTH</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <div>
                            <p>Teaser number 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Donec interdum dapibus lectus eu rhoncus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                        <h4>Sub-heading different</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                        <h4>Sub-heading 4</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div>
                            <p>Link to detailed page number 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have not incorporated any custom CSS yet except for the .row-centered, which is as simple as this:

```
.row-centered {
text-align:center;}
```

What should I do to fix the problem?  Thank you very much!

Here are the screenshots:
[Example](http://i745.photobucket.com/albums/xx95/yvr_craigslist/example.png~original)

Comment: Seems like you are missing some code above first `row-centered`. Can you post the full code which is wrapping the rows?

Comment: Thanks, Manoj for pointing that out.  I have added back the first line.

Comment: Quick tip: You don't need the `.row-centered` class, there is already `.text-center`, see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Comment: Hi Manoj, did you share a "flexbox" suggestion earlier?  For whatever reasons, I am unable to see that anymore.  Do you know what might have gone wrong?  Sorry this is my first post on stackoverflow and I am still trying to figure out how this works.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Topgun**, Hi there. To get this to stay inline with each other.
My approach is to adjust the title font size at 2 media breakpoints.
You can change this to suit what suits you, I went just a little smaller to show the effect here.
I also at a breakpoint add the height value to main text part you have too.
I used `min-height` here rather than a fixed height. Because when they stack on a small screen the text need room to expand down. 
Your code had lost of extra `divs` and seemed like lots of hidden block padders.

I went through this and removed a lot just to pull it back to what is only needed here for this demo.
Go through the code and see the difference.

What I also added here was `col-xs-12` into your img `class`.
As you will see now when resized down to a small screen size the image goes **full width** and does not stay to the left with a big space to the right.
To center the text you just need to use the `class` of `text-center` once in each of the 2 `rows`.

Hope that this gets you started for how you want it to look now.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/aw7nr3o7/)**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

@media(max-width:1200px) {
.adjust-fontsize{
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-weight: 600;
}
}    
@media(max-width:992px) {
.adjust-fontsize{
    font-size:1.0em;
}
.row-height{
    min-height:70px;
}    
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
    
    <div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
            
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="adjust-fontsize">HEADER NUMBER 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-lg-12 row-height">
                <p>Teaser number 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit, interdum consectetur elit. 
                Donec interdum dapibus lectus rhoncus.
                </p>
            </div>
                
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                    <h4>Sub-heading short</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                    <h4>Sub-heading longer</h4>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <p>Link to detailed page 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    
    
    
    
        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="adjust-fontsize">HEADER DIFFERENT LENGTH</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-xs-12 row-height">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>Teaser number 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
                    <br>Donec interdum dapibus lectus eu rhoncus.
                    </p>
                </div>    
            </div>
        
            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                    <h4>Sub-heading different</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <img class="col-xs-12 img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Square" alt="">
                    <h4>Sub-heading 4</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <p>Link to detailed page number 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi AngularJR,  thanks for the suggestions.  The reason I had a ton of extra <divs> was to keep the "proportional padding" between the components across different devices.  Is there any better way to achieve the same result?  It will be great if you can share.  Going back to my original question, if changing the font size for different media breakpoints is not an option, what else can we do to resolve the alignment issue at hand?  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Topgun.  1st, this post question... yes there is but it is not supported by older browsers. `position:flex;`. **Manoj Kumar** actually posted a working example using this but overnight it was deleted. It would have been good if that option was left up. When using the option to change font size you can get a more consistent look across all screens and not have the main title stack, which you will still have using `flex`.  2nd question... it is best to probably try using `col-xs-offset-2` for example when needed. Do you know how to use this class? I can help here if you do.

Comment: Hi AngularJR, was Manoj's post deleted by the system or did he remove himself?  Again, this is my first post on stackoverflow and I have no idea how a post gets deleted overnight.  I agree with you that the main titles should better be handled by varying the font sizes so they never wrap to the second line.  But the flexbox option does appear to be an interesting option for components like the teasers.  Would you agree?  Would you mind telling me more about flexbox?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do agree with that. It would have only been deleted by Manoj I think. When I said overnight, it was just referring to my time here.  Yes, the look of this would look far better for the title to stay on one line. And if you just adjust what every amount of text you actually have in the title ... work / find the largest font size you can set this to for small screen sizes. At the end of the day... it is about how it looks and the max support on browsers. Also, you can add more breakpoints to step the font size at each screen size too. That will really help too.